# Code folding isn't working in Management Studio?

Tags: sql, ssms

I have SQL Management Studio `10.50.1600.1`, and I have `Outline statements` turned on in `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Transact-SQL -> IntelliSense`, but alas it's not giving me the expander on the `BEGIN` statements.

I've also verified that IntelliSense is enabled for the query window I'm in, and SQL CMD Mode is disabled.

Further, I've verified that I'm not connected to a down leveled server, I'm connected to a server that is version `10.50.2500.0`.

Finally, I've verified the version of the database itself, it's a `v100` database.

**NOTE:** the actual IntelliSense isn't working either, and this is a SQL Express instance, I don't know if that makes any difference at all but I thought I might mention it.

Comment: Do you have any Visual Studio installations? If so, what version and service pack?

Comment: @beargle, yes, I have 2005, 2008, 2010, and 2012.

Comment: What service pack for 2010?

Comment: @beargle, my apologies for missing that additional request. I'm on 2010 SP1 and 2012 Update 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify your installation meets [these requirements](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173434.aspx). Install [SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30437). This should get SSMS version to 10.50.4000. After the service pack is applied, check to see if the problem is resolved.

If this doesn't resolve the intellisense issue, the next step is to reinstall [VS 2010 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691).

More information on the conflict can be found through [KB2531482](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2531482). I have seen installations where intellisense is still broken with SSMS 2008 R2 SP2. The VS 2010 SP1 reinstall was able to resolve.

Comment: Does this then have something to do with the fact that I've got the database on my SQL Express instance?

Comment: This lead me to my answer. The issue is that it was on a SQL Express instance. When I moved it to a real SQL Server instance, code folding worked.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me with ssms 2014 and 2016 preview.

I can't be arsed to try and reinstall this and that.

So I just created some keyboard shortcuts for "hide selection" and "toggle outlining expansion".  So I have to choose what gets outlined, but it's better than nothing.  Not too much trouble.  A workable solution for me, may work for you.